# "system and device such as that disclosed in U.S. Patent No." — what does "that" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

> The bioassay aspect of the present invention herein may be carried out in a testing subunit or test cartridge designed for use with a bench-top or portable testing system and device such as **that** disclosed in U.S. Patent No. 9,023,640, which is incorporated by reference herein, in its entirety.

What does "that" refer to in the paragraph above? The device? The system and device as a single unit?

Comment: Though this  queries answers haven't been accepted, and is several months old with no activity, I'd be interested in seeing where this quote actually came from if it still interests you to clarify.

Comment: @GWarner https://patents.google.com/patent/US9850547

Answer (score 1):

A 'system and device' similar in function and use 'as disclosed in U.S...'

Comment: How can the OP identify this for themself next time?

Comment: Good point. '**Those that** are' certainly is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "that" here is essentially the sense defined in 4a of https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that:

> 4a: the one : the thing : the kind : SOMETHING, ANYTHING
>   // the truth of *that* which is true
>   // the senses are *that* whereby we experience the world
>   // what's *that* you say

That is, it means basically "...such as **the one** disclosed..."

Note that this use is not very common, and usually comes up mostly in set phrases or, as in this case, in some legal or technical contexts (patent filings tend to have a lot of unusual English constructs which even native speakers can sometimes have a hard time with, due to a complicated history of legal language, etc).